# Access to mobile gallery from HTML/Angular application

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

How can I access to Android's mobile photo gallery from an Angular 7 application to pick a photo and upload it to a server? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use standard upload control such as:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```

User will then choose which file to upload and from where. You can't control this directly from a web site.

You might get a bit more control with native applications and asking for user's permissions to access photos, but thats likely out of the scope for this question.